# Document set parent/child relationship search

Tags: 2013, search, document-set

We are working with Document Sets and have set them up with some custom metadata and different content types that can be loaded into them. We've found several good tutorials about setting up the docsets and sharing columns, [like this one](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/document-sets-making-your-metadata-shine).

When I search in my library and find the child of a parent document I don't see anything in the main part of the returned result that let's me know it is part of a document set.

If I hover over the result there is a **View  library** link in the preview/hover panel link which takes me into the document set.

Also if I search on the name or metadata associated with the document set parent, I get a search result that shows a folder icon indicating it is a set, but no indication of what the children for that set are.

The question is, how does a docset know what children it has and conversely given a child document how to I find its parent?

Is there a way to create a custom search result type for document sets or the children of document sets?

Comment: It seems there is a property called ows_FileRef which shows the path of a document. We are able to use SPServices to get that directly from the library, but I can't seem to get it to map to a searchable property....

Comment: Ive found built in managed properties called OriginalPath and ParentLink. They seem to replace the FileRef. Something along the lines of "If this result has an item child count of 1 or more, use it's original path to find other items that have a matching parent link...at least that seems like it might work!